# Extract words (multiple whitespace) starting with # by regular expression

Tags: java, android, regex

I have a problem with my regular expression:

```
String regex = "(?<=[\\s])#\\w+\\s";
```

I want a regex that formats a string like this:

```
"This is a Text     #tag1 #tag2 #tag3"
```

With the regular expression, I get the last two values as result but not tag1 - because there is more than one whitespace. But i want all 3 of them!

I tried some variations, but nothing worked.

Comment: You want all except the first tag, or always just the last two tags? You want to include the `#` tag or not?

Comment: ouh there was a typing error, sorry. i edited again.  i want all 3 tags including the #

Comment: You want only all tags at the end of the string, or anywhere in the string? Is it always 3 tags, or a varying amount? Is it a criteria that there has to be 2 or more spaces before `#tag1` for it to be a valid match?

Answer (score 1):

Use this regular expression:

```
(?<=(^|\\S)\\s)#\\w+(?=\\s|$)
```

[Here's a demo.](http://ideone.com/7PbWK)

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit unclear from your question what you're really after, so I've put up some simple alternatives:

**To capture all the tags in the string, we can use a lookbehind:**

```
((?<=\\s|^)#\\w+)
```

---

**To capture all the tags at the end of the string, we can use a lookahead:**

```
(#\\w+(?=\\s#)|#\\w+$)
```

---

**If there's always three tags at the end, there's no need for a lookaround:**

```
(#\\w+)\s(#\\w+)\s(#\\w+)$
```